# base64 String is too long to send via Fetch HTTP API

Tags: javascript, php, api, http, base64

I have a base64 image that is a very long character count and when I try to send it via Fetch POST API it gets cut off and makes the image unacceptable by my PHP file server-side. The base64 is the b64data variable in my below code. Any solutions or ideas would be appreciated!

```
function submitPhoto(){ 


fetch('http://fanbeauties.com/app/submit-photo.php?pass=MY_PASS', { 
    method: "POST", 
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
    },
    body: 'name='+name+'&email='+email+'&market='+market+'&picture='+b64data
     });


};
```

The PHP:

```
<?php



      $title = $_POST['name'];
        $market = $_POST['market'];
        $account = "414890";
        $date = date("Y-m-d");
        $pass = $_GET['pass'];
        $image = $_POST['picture'];
        $title = $_POST['name'];
        //$source_type = "app";



        if($pass == "Fan412") { 

            //Clean base64 String
            //$image = str_replace(' ', '', $image);

            //Convert base64 into image
            $filename_path = md5(time().uniqid()).".jpg";
            $decoded=base64_decode($image);
            file_put_contents("../MY_FOLDER/".$filename_path,$decoded);

            // Insert Info into Database
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (account, date, title, market, image) VALUES ('$account', '$date', '$title', '$market', '$filename_path')");           

            // close connection 
            $mysqli->close();


        } else {

            die();

        } ?>
```

Comment: `a very long character count` define "very long" ... I think 200 is very long ... you may think otherwise ... `unacceptable by my PHP file server-side` - simple solution is to *increase the allowable POST data length PHP configuration item*

Comment: You might need to use `FormData` for large uploads.

Comment: There is no defined limit for the payload max size in a HTTP POST.  PHP may impose a limit in its config but that can be modified.

Comment: Are you using any javascript framework? Because you are using POST method but you are passing the data like GET method.

Comment: @CarlSare POST data can be sent in either URL-encoded format or `multipart/form-data`.

Comment: @JaromandaX over 28,000 characters so very long.

Comment: @CarlSare I am using Fuse Tools to develop an app. I believe I can add to the body somehow but not sure how.

Comment: @Barmar, Yeah I know. But that's where the issue came from because the URL has limitations in character. He may try to pass the data like..

data: {
  "name":name,
  "email": email,
   .......
}

Comment: @CarlSare I would like to use the data: {} format but doesn't the whole thing have to be JSON encoded then? I'd like to stay away from the JSON for this.

Comment: I am not suggest use base64 encode image file because it will increase file size.

Comment: @CarlSare I don't think `Fetch` allows a plain object for `body`, that's a jQuery feature. And it simply converts it to the corresponding URL-encoded body.

Comment: @winlans Well what the PHP does is then decode the base64 and generate an image before saving so I am not worried about that. Just need to POST the full base64 to the server-side.

Comment: @MikeBarbaro Have you tried using `FormData`?

Comment: @Barmar I am not too familiar with FormData. Is there a resource I can refer to?

Comment: @MikeBarbaro Google "javascript formdata"

Comment: @Barmar Looking now. Thanks.

Comment: @MikeBarbaro modify php.ini and increase max.post

Comment: @winlans I already did increase the post_max to a very large amount.

Comment: @MikeBarbaro what's the error message?

Comment: @MikeBarbaro nginx or Apache?

Comment: @MikeBarbaro 28k is nothing for a post. PHP defaults to I think an 8mb limit by default.

Comment: @Joe yes but the issue is that the string is too long to send.

Comment: My point is: it is NOT too long to send.  You have some other kind of error.

Comment: @Joe I edited the post to include my PHP I am using.

Answer (score -1):

how about cut the base64_code into pieces then 
post them before submit the whole form...

postData
{ 
 'code': one piece_code,
 'current_position': 1,
 'full_pieces_count': a count you cut pieces
}

in php you can use redis to cache the base64_pieces with sorted_set piece1 piece2 ...( the score use the current_position you post)
after final pieces upload success... 
combine them into pic to save then give js an img_url
then submit the whole form

btw: set the max length to post all the string...if it's too long...cut it and post them async/sync